# How can I implement infinite scroll when we get close to bottom[FLUTTER]?

Tags: flutter, scroll, lazy-loading, infinite

When I use the following code, I can fetch new datas when I reach the bottom of the listview

```
  controller.addListener(() {
    if(controller.position.pixels==controller.position.maxScrollExtent){
      postController.fetchNewPosts(postController.postList.last.timeupdated);
    }
  });
```

But I want to fetch them Not when I reach at bottom, but when I get close to it so that users dont wait when they reach to bottom.

```
child: Obx(() => NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
      onNotification: (ScrollNotification notification){
        if(notification.metrics.maxScrollExtent > notification.metrics.pixels &&
            notification.metrics.maxScrollExtent - notification.metrics.pixels <=
                60.0){
          print(postController.postList.last.post);
          postController.fetchNewPosts(postController.postList.last.timeupdated);
          print('DENEME');
        }
        return false;
      },
      child: ListView.builder(
          controller: controller,
          itemCount: postController.postList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Card(
              child: Row(
```

When I use this code, It trigers the function 15 times in one second...
how can I do it properly?

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a NotificationListener like this, because is executing all the time when built.

try to add a ScrollController

```
final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
```

after that add a scroll listener method

```
void _scrollListener() {
    if (scrollController.offset >= scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent &&
        !scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
       print(postController.postList.last.post);
      postController.fetchNewPosts(postController.postList.last.timeupdated);
      print('DENEME');
      }
    }
  }
```

and in the initState add this listener to scroll controller

```
@override
  void initState() {
    scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but it doesn't do what I wanted to do.
It fetches new posts when I reach to bottom but I want to fetch them before I reach, but when I get close to

Comment: It works properly, but I want to fetch datas slightly before I reached at bottom

Answer (score 0):

change to :

```
  controller.addListener(() {
    if(controller.position.pixels==controller.position.maxScrollExtent-200){
      postController.fetchNewPosts(postController.postList.last.timeupdated);
    }
  });
```

200 is the distance before reaching the bottom, set any value you like

Comment: thanks for your helping but it never works, I've tried it for many times before. When you scroll, you skip that pixel, you never trigger the function in that pixel, you simply skip it

Answer (score 0):

I implement with https://pub.dev/packages/inview_notifier_list this library.
In low tier device, it may cause performance issue. Like jank, frame issue.

Here are example.
Hope it will be help you.

```
SafeArea(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          InViewNotifierCustomScrollView(
            physics: Platform.isAndroid ? ClampingScrollPhysics() : RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics(),
            isInViewPortCondition: widget.inViewPortCondition ??
                    (double deltaTop, double deltaBottom, double vpHeight) {
                  return deltaTop < (0.7 * vpHeight) && deltaBottom > (0.7 * vpHeight);
                },
            endNotificationOffset: mw(500),
            onListEndReached: () async{
              if(_list1.length == _totCnt) {
                setState(() {
                  _noMoreItem = 'No more Models';
                });
              } else {
                if(_moreItems) {
                  setState(() {
                    _isLoad = true;
                    _moreItems = false;
                    _offset = _offset + 30;
                  });
                  bool _rrr = await getModelList($user.accessToken, $user.appInfo);
                  if(_rrr) {
                    setState(() {
                      _moreItems = true;
                    });
                  }
                } else {
                }
              }
            },
            controller: _bscrollController,
            slivers: [
              SliverAppBar(
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                elevation: 0,
                brightness: Brightness.light,
                title: Text('Models', style: Ts.h15bb(),),
                actions: [
                  GestureDetector(
                      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SearchPage()));
                      },
                      child: Icon(Icons.search, size: mw(26),)),
                  SizedBox(width: mw(10),),
                  GestureDetector(
                      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CartPage()));
                      },
                      child:  Stack(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: mw(13), right: mw(18)),
                            child: Image.asset('assets/pickling_cart.png', width: mw(18), height: mw(22),),
                          ),
                          $user.cartCnt == '0' ? Container():Positioned(
                              top: mw(9),
                              right: mw(10),
                              child: ClipRRect(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                                child: Container(
                                  height: mw(16),
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: mw(5), right: mw(5), bottom: mw(2)),
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  child: Center(child: Text('${$user.cartCnt}', style: Ts.ctwb(),),),
                                ),
                              )
                          )
                        ],
                      )),
                ],
              ),

              _totCnt == 0 ?
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:mw(50)),
                  child:
                  Center(
                      child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text('There are no models!', style: Ts.h3bb()),
                      SizedBox(height:mw(5)),
                      Text(':X', style: Ts.bd1gm(),),
                    ],
                  ))
                ),
              ):
              SliverPadding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: mw(2)),
                sliver: SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                    (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          ModelItem(imgURL,index,$user),
                          Divider(thickness: 1, color: Du.lightGrey(),)
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                      childCount: _list1.length
                  )
                )
              )

            ],
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
```